# Difference between Paypal Payment Button and Web Checkout

Tags: paypal

There are 2 ways to integrate paypal with web site, [Payment Button](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/) and [Web Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/web-checkout/).

The former seems to be easier than the latter, and we won't even to [sign up an APP](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps) if we choose Payment Button.

Besides the difficulty of integration, is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

It's basically just HTML forms vs. web service API's.

The buttons are generally setup for a single item or for the PayPal cart, which I wouldn't recommend using.  If you're going to be using your own shopping cart, you could actually just use the [cart upload method](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/), which is still [PayPal Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#wps) (html forms.)

If you are comfortable with API's, though, I'd recommend going with [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#ec), which uses API's but still doesn't require creating an "app" in the PayPal network.

If you happen to be working with PHP you might want to take a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/).  It would make the API calls very simple for you.